# Auth Stack Navigation with "Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component"

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

In react-native I am using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) v5 and I have two stack navigators: one for public screens and one for authenticated screen.

App -> Navigation Container -> PublicStack || AuthStack

PublicStack = SelectPlatform -> Login
AuthStack = Home

I am using MobX store where I have a flag (named isLoggedIn) which gets updated when the user loggs in. According to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ I am returning this in the render method of App:

```
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  {this.props.store.auth.loggedInIndicator ? (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
      {screens}
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  ) : (
    <PublicStack.Navigator>
      {screens}
     </PublicStack.Navigator>
  )}
```

When I navigate from Select Platform Screen to Login Screen and when i change the loggedInIndicator (which is in the store) I get the warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component
```

The error is pretty self-explanatory because I am aware that I am causing re-render of the parent by making action into the child component, therefore rendering it with different stack navigation. Do you know any workaround? I tried searching in other posts, but i didn't find anything similar to my case. Additionally I am using Class components where I cannot use hooks.